# How do you plot the single contribution of each term in a 3rd order polynomial in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, lme4-nlme, polynomial

I am fitting a model in R with the glmer function of the lme4 package. For one of the variables I use a 3rd order orthogonal polynomial. I now want to plot each polynomial's order in a separate plot to determine how each of the 'single' orders vary across different subjects. I apologies that this is not the proper terminology, I have been searching for a few days but I cannot find what I am looking for. In the code below is my attempt to solve this problem. I

1. created some synthetic data resembling the R data.frame I use
2. fitted the model I plan to use
3. plot (what I think are) the polynomials' single fit.

Any help is appreciated, especially if you think what I am doing does not make any sense.

```
# source('~/Dropbox/stackOverflow/Q_glmerPoly.R')
## data generation
set.seed(10022017)
nObs <- 125
nSubs <- 2
nTrials <- 8
nPoints <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(pp = rep(c(1, nSubs), each = nPoints), 
            binTime = rep(rep(1:nObs, nTrials), nSubs),
            cond = rep(rep(c('a', 's'), each = nObs), nTrials),
            target = sample(c(0,1), (nSubs * nPoints), replace = TRUE))

## polynomial
t <- poly(unique(dat$binTime), 3)
dat$ot1 <- t[ ,1]
dat$ot2 <- t[ ,2]
dat$ot3 <- t[ ,3]

## model fitting
require(lme4)
icond = 's'
m1 <- glmer(target ~ (ot1 + ot2 + ot3) + (ot1 + ot2 + ot3 | pp), 
    data = dat, 
    subset = dat$cond == icond, 
    family = binomial, 
    control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
        optCtrl = list(maxfun=100000))
)

## plotting
x11()
polys = poly(1:nObs, 3)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

subs <- unique(dat$pp)
isub <- 1

polynomial <- cbind(rep(1, 1, nObs), polys)
randomEffect <- t(matrix(as.numeric(ranef(m1)$pp[subs[isub], 1:4]), 
  length(ranef(m1)$pp[subs[isub], 1:4]), nObs))
fixedEffect <- t(matrix(as.numeric(fixef(m1)), length(fixef(m1)), nObs))

modelCI <- (polynomial * (fixedEffect + randomEffect))

plot(plogis(modelCI[, 2]), ylab = 'probs',
    main = '1st Order', type = 'l', bty = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))

plot(plogis(modelCI[, 3]), ylab = 'probs',
    main = '2nd Order', type = 'l', bty = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))

plot(plogis(modelCI[,4]), ylab = 'probs',
    main = '3rd Order', type = 'l', bty = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))

plot(plogis(modelCI[, 1] + modelCI[, 2] + modelCI[, 3] + modelCI[,4]),
    ylab = 'probs',
    main = 'all three', type = 'l', bty = 'n', ylim = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: Your question appears to depend critically on the meaning of "how each of the 'single' orders vary across different subjects."  Could you please explain that more fully?

Comment: I want to have a set of four plots for each subject. The first plot should represent the first order polynomial, the second plot should represent the second order polynomial and the third plot should represent the second order polynomial. The fourth plot should display the sum of it. I understood that a cubic polynomial is represented as: f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d. So the first plot would contain only cx, the second only bx^2, and so on. I hope this clarifies things

Comment: It does clarify things.  I wish to point out that "the first order polynomial" is not well-defined.  This is because the use of $x$ as the variable is arbitrary: it shouldn't matter to your model if you were to shift $x$ by a constant, say $u$. You would get exactly the same fit. But that would change the linear coefficient $c$ into $c+2bu+3au^2$, demonstrating this coefficient has little or no meaning for the model.  Perhaps you should look into *orthogonal polynomials*: those do have some meaning in a regression model.

Comment: I thought that since `poly` gives orthogonal polynomials by default I was covered. But I might not understand what you mean...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't inspect your code: I was responding to what you wrote and what you wrote doesn't mention orthogonal polynomials at all.  If this is actually a question about statistics and not just about how to do something in `R`, then it is important to make the nature of your question understandable without having to work through the code.

Comment: Apologies, I did not mean to confuse you. I tried to formulate my question as clearly as possible but because I do not have a mathematical background I find it difficult to describe these concepts. Therefore I added the code hoping it could help explaining what I am trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53408/discussion-between-helloworld-and-whuber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! The solution is closer to a 'prof of concept' than to a proper answer, but I believe it shows my approach is not wrong. Basically I assumed that if my approach is right, when I compute the whole model I should get the same results than when using the `predict` function on my `glmer` model. Since the the outcome of `predict` is identical to my approach I assume I am doing it right. Of course I am assuming that what if the approach is correct for the whole model it should also be correct for the single polynomials, but I trust my answer will be trashed if someone disagrees. Below is the code I used:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
predictions <- data.frame(target = predict(m1, data.frame(
        pp = dat$pp[dat$pp == subs[isub]],
        ot1 = dat$ot1[dat$pp == subs],
        ot2 = dat$ot2[dat$pp == subs],
        ot3 = dat$ot3[dat$pp == subs]
    ) , type = "response"),
    binTime = as.numeric(dat$binTime[dat$pp == subs])
)

avePred <- aggregate(target ~ binTime, data = predictions, FUN = mean)
plot(avePred, main = 'fitted data', type = 'l', bty = 'n')

randomEffect <- t(matrix(as.numeric(ranef(m1)$pp[subs[isub], ]), 
     length(ranef(m1)$pp[subs[isub], ]), nObs))

fixedEffect <- t(matrix(as.numeric(fixef(m1)), length(fixef(m1)), nObs)) 

modelCI <- (polynomial * (fixedEffect + randomEffect))
modelCI <- plogis(modelCI[, 1] + modelCI[, 2] + modelCI[, 3] + modelCI[,4])
lines(y = modelCI, x = unique(dat$binTime), col = 'green')
legend('center', # 'topright', 
    legend = c('glmerPredict', 'myPredict'),
    lty = c(1, 1),
    col = c('black', 'green'),
    text.col = c('black', 'green'), bty = 'n')
```